# solve $t^5+t+1=0$

Tags: polynomials

I honestly don't have any idea at all on how to solve this.
I am asked to find solutions under $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{C}$ respectively but this seems impossible to solve without a computer.

Does anyone know how to go about this? Thank you

Comment: It shouldn't be hard to graph it at least and figure out how many roots it has.  Because it has a real simple derivative. By the IVT there's at least one root between $-1$ and $0$.  I suspect it only has one, but I didn't do the details so not sure.

Comment: Maybe works $(t^{2}+t+1)(t^{3}-t^{2}+1)=0$

Comment: Yeah isn't the derivative always positive?  So it can have only one root.

Comment: It has only one real root. Do you think you can factor it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$t^5+t+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\left(t^2+t+1\right)\left(t^3-t^2+1\right)=0$$

Split into two equations:

- Use the 'abc-formula' to find the solution to: 
  $$t^2+t+1=0$$
- $$t^3-t^2+1=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

  ---

Eliminate the quadratic term by substituting $x=t-\frac{1}{3}$:

---

$$1-\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+\left(x+\frac{1}{3}\right)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^3-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{25}{27}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

If $x=y+\frac{\lambda}{y}$ then $y=\frac{1}{2}\left(x+\sqrt{x^2-4\lambda}\right)$:

---

$$25+\frac{1}{3}\left(-y-\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)+\left(y+\frac{\lambda}{y}\right)^3=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Multiply both sides by $y^3$ and collect in terms of $y$;

Substitute $\lambda=\frac{1}{9}$ and then $z=y^3$, yielding a quadratic equation in the variable $z$:

---

$$z^2+\frac{25z}{27}+\frac{1}{729}=0$$

Comment: Omg. Where did you learn all that?

Comment: Is "abc-formula" another name for the quadratic formula? I've never heard it called that before

Comment: @ziggurism yes it is!

Comment: Seems like you could also justify the name for the Pythagorean theorem if you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

$$t^5+t+1=(t^2+t+1)(t^3-t^2+1)=0$$

The equation $t^2+t+1=0$ can easily be solved. The equation $t^3-t^2+1=0$ can be solved either numerically or with the (complicated) formula for cubic equations.

Answer (score 1):

For $\mathbb Q$ one can use the rational root theorem.

This gives that the only $1$ and $-1$ can be rational roots, but they clearly aren't.